# Not doing Animations and Moving to the next screen

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm going through the Sams Android Development book, and I put an animation code and a code to move it to the next screen. I tested it on my phone and the AVD and it's not working. Here's the code:

```
public class QuizSplashActivity extends QuizActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    TextView logo1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewTopTitle);
    Animation fade1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
    logo1.startAnimation(fade1);

    TextView logo2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BottomView1);
    Animation fade3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
    logo1.startAnimation(fade3);

    Animation spinin= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_anim);
    LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(spinin);
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout01); {
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getChildCount(); i++) {
        TableRow row = (TableRow) table.getChildAt(i);
        row.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
    }
    }



Animation fade2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,  R.anim.custom_anim);
fade2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation){
        startActivity(new Intent(QuizSplashActivity.this, QuizMenuActivity.class));
        QuizSplashActivity.this.finish();
    }
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation a) { }
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation a) { }
});
}



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    TextView logo1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewTopTitle);
            logo1.clearAnimation();
    TextView logo2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BottomView1);
            logo2.clearAnimation();

}
}
`
```

Please help, I want to move onto the next chapter.

Again, if I run this code, the animation doesn't run and the app doesn't move onto the next screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `onAnimationEnd` of `fade2` is where you start your next Activity but I don't see you using it anywhere.

I think you've got confused about which views you want to animate and which animations to use here:

```
    TextView logo1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewTopTitle);
    Animation fade1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
    logo1.startAnimation(fade1); // <----- is this right?

    TextView logo2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BottomView1);
    Animation fade3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
    logo1.startAnimation(fade3); // <----- and this one?
```

Also, `onAnimationEnd` is not reliable.  You can take a look at `setRepeatCount()` and `setRepeatMode()` and play around with those but there are multiple bugs with them and worse, those bugs vary between Android version.

Instead, you can use a delayed Runnable to do your "post animation" work:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        view.clearAnimation();  // <--- whichever view you are animating

        startActivity(new Intent(QuizSplashActivity.this, QuizMenuActivity.class));
        QuizSplashActivity.this.finish();
    }
}, fade2.getDuration());
```

This runnable will be delayed for however long `fade2` is set to animate for.  When it fires, it clears the current animation and starts the activity.

Good luck!

Comment: I keep getting a "view cannot be resolved" error. How do I fix that?

Comment: We can't guess.  Exactly when and where?

Comment: "view.clearAnimation(R.id.BottomView1);
          startActivity(new Intent(QuizSplashActivity.this, QuizMenuActivity.class));
          QuizSplashActivity.this.finish();
      }"

In this view variable, what you told me to input into the code.

Comment: Of course `view` is not defined.  Please see the comment on that line.  `view` is whatever view you are animating.  I don't know which one it is because you are not using `fade2` in the code you have shown.  I just used `view` as a placeholder for whichever view you should be using.  Please read my answer again.

Comment: I used the fade2 (after I changed some things) as the view. Now I'm getting two errors at the same line,"Multiple markers at this line
 - The method clearActivity() is undefined for the type Animation
 - Cannot refer to a non-final variable fade2 inside an inner class defined in a different "

Comment: OK, time for some "Hello World" tutorials.  `fade2` is your animation.  A `View` is what you apply the animation to.  You need to go back to basics I'm afraid.

Comment: Didn't even realize I used it in the onPause() menu. *Duh*
Thanks for all your help! And sorry for the headaches :)

Comment: Just put in the next screen and it's not moving to the next screen. It stays on the original splash screen. What can I do?